# PHP openssl_encrypt script to emulate this Java encryption function (also next stage would be to decrypt)

Tags: java, php, encryption, openssl, blowfish

I've been working on a PHP script to work with a Java script, they both need to encrypt and decrypt using the same procedure/iv/key/method etc so that data passed both directions is translatable.

I believe I need to be using opennssl_encrypt, and openssl_decrypt and am avoiding mcrypt, and I'm most of the way there but something is going awry and I cannot figure out what is wrong.

Script basically takes the salts (x3) and runs a loop up to the number of salts, suffixing the input/looped value each time.

This is the Java encrypt:

```
VALUE = "myinputvalue"; // test value for string tests
ALGORITHM = "Blowfish";
MODE = "Blowfish/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
IV = "myivmyiv"; //random test value, 8 characters
KEY = "atextstringencryptionkey";
SALT = {"salt1111", "salt2222", "salt3333"};
ITERATIONS = SALT.length;

String encrypt(String value) {
    try{
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(KEY.getBytes(), ALGORITHM);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(MODE);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(IV.getBytes()));
        String valueToEncode = value;
        for(int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++){
            valueToEncode = SALT[i] + valueToEncode;
            byte[] values = cipher.doFinal(valueToEncode.getBytes());
            valueToEncode = Base64.encodeToString(values, Base64.DEFAULT);
            Log.i("Encryption " + (i + 1), valueToEncode);
        }
        return valueToEncode;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
}
```

This is my PHP script:

```
$valueToEncode = "myinputvalue";
$cipher_method = "BF-CBC";
$enc_iv = "myivmyiv";
$options = 0;
$enc_key = "atextstringencryptionkey";
$salts = array('salt1111', 'salt2222', 'salt3333');
$arrayLength = count($salts);
$iterations = array();
$i = 0;
while ($i < $arrayLength) {
    $iterations[$i] = strlen($salts[$i]);
    $i++;
}


        $s = 0;

        $valueToEncode = $value;

        while ($s < $arrayLength) {

            $valueToEncode = $salts[$s] . $valueToEncode;

            $valueToEncode = openssl_encrypt($valueToEncode, $cipher_method, $enc_key, $options, $enc_iv);

            $s++;
        }

        $return = $valueToEncode;
```

This is as close as I can get, it's 100% the first loop, but then the end of the ouput goes wrong when passed back through. I'm sorry if I'm missing something obvious, I'm pretty ok with PHP but encryption is new to me and I've searched and tried a lot and have come up empty.

I've tried implementing base64_decode/base64_encode to try and get closer to how Java is doing it), but it throws it all way out and I hope what I'm missing is easy and obvious to you clever folks.

Comment: I know that's not what you want to hear, but there's so much wrong with just the base (Java) example that you'd be way better off replacing instead of trying to replicate it. Cryptography isn't something you casually figure out; it's a huge mistake to approach it like any other routine development task ... I highly recommend that you hire a professional to do it for you, or at the very least outsorce it to a battle-tested library.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, and I appreciate what you're saying. This is a simple closed system and we just want to avoid sending plain text strings, hence being a simple to/fro string encryption.

Comment: Some worse news: your loop doesn't look anything like the Java code. There is a while loop in there, and a variable `$s`... why? This seems like a way of randomly trying things until the right answer pops up - and it is not going to help you. Try to mimic the Java code to the best of your abilities, including identifier names etc.

Comment: Sorry $s is to be used in the while loop (I've corrected my $i to $s). I've spent some time trying to understand and have ut together something I thought was suffice. I'd appreciate pointers. I'll review my code to see what I can do. 
I'm getting the first loop value correct, it's the subsequent loops where it's going wrong so I didn't think I was that far out procedurally.

Comment: If you're only trying to not send plaintext over the wire, just use TLS, that's what it is for.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue I was having was caused by Java creating line breaks (\n value) at the end of each iteration within the try loop.

These \n values were removed and now the outputs match.

FYI my PHP decrypt is this (forgive my lazy loop):

```
        $s = $arrayLength - 1;

    while ($s >= 0) {

        $valueToDecode = openssl_decrypt($valueToDecode, $cipher_method, $enc_key, $options, $enc_iv);
        $valueToDecode = substr($valueToDecode, $block_size);

        $s--;
    }
```

Thanks to those that offered feedback.